# What happens to null character when string is reversed using reverse loop

Tags: c++, string, loops, null-character

I am new with strings in C++. I am just confused with the working of the code below (used to reverse a string).

```
std:: string    rev;

        for(int i=  str.size()-1;   i>=0;   --i)
        {
            rev.push_back(str[i]);  
        }

        std:: cout<<"   Reversed=   "<<rev<<endl;
```

The Problem is that the last character of a string is null character `'\0'`. So, when the loop runs for the first iteration, it should place a null character at the start of `rev` and one more thing, here the string `rev` may not be null terminated because `'\0'` is not assigned as the last character of string.

But when I execute the Program, it works fine. I know I am wrong while thinking all this. Can anyone explain the working please? I shall be glad and Thankful to you :)

Comment: Hint: You can greatly simplify that code with this single line: `std::reverse_copy(begin(str), end(str), std::back_inserter(rev));`

Comment: Thanks @ChristianHackl

Answer (score 4):

The null terminator is not actually considered part of a `std::string`.  It only comes into play when you call `c_str()`.  So `size()` and `length()` do not include a terminator.  And in fact you can put null characters into the middle of a `std::string` and everything will still work, except for `c_str()` (if your string may contain nulls you should use `data()` and `size()`).

Comment: If the string contains nulls, then there are very high chances that the OP is actually looking for `std::vector<unsigned char>`.

Answer (score 1):

The '/0' operator is added automatically, so you are looping only till the character just before '/0'. It's always there basically, so you are not seeing any changes.

Comment: It's `'\0'`, and it's not an operator.